# Do I need multiple AsyncTask classes to connect to network?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have one(1) AsyncTask class that connects to an API from network.
The API gets user profile from mySQL database based on username and password that is passed via POST.
If I have another API that saves a new User Profile to mySql based on username and password too, do I need to create a new AsyncTask class?
Does this mean that whenever I need to connect to a new API, I will need to create a new class?

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need to. At least you will need to build separate functions for each API to parse the JSON received.

I recommend you to use some library for the purpose. Retrofit along with Gson is preferred.